# Reading json from url

Tags: json, go, google-sheets

The endpoint was created in Google SpreadSheet, which is here:

```
url01 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/1/public/values?alt=json"
```

The Git repo is here...    which is where I will keep the updated code as I fix it. My hunch is that I am screwing up the struct when I import the file.  The code prints nothing.  So, could I get some advice on what is going wrong please.

```
        package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type GSSS struct {
    Feed GSSSfeed `json:"feed"`
}

type GSSSfeed struct {
    Version string   `json:"version"`
    TITLE   GSSTitle `json:"title"`
    // Entry   []GSSSEntry `json:"entry"`
}
type GSSTitle struct {
    T string `json:"t"`
}

func main() {
    url01 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/1/public/values?alt=json"
    //url02 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/2/public/values?alt=json"
    //url03 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/3/public/values?alt=json"
    //url04 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/4/public/values?alt=json"
    //url05 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/5/public/values?alt=json"
    println("=============  starting main =============")

    // res, err := http.Get("https://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
    res, err := http.Get(url01)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err.Error())
    // }

    var m GSSS
    // err := json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
    //json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&m)
    // json.NewDecoder([]byte(body)).Decode(&m)

    // json.NewDecoder([]byte(res.Body)).Decode(&m)
    json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&m)

    //err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Whoops...:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("============  about to print m ============")
    fmt.Println(m.Feed.TITLE.T)
    fmt.Println("============  about to print m2 ============")
    fmt.Println(m.Feed)
    fmt.Println("============  about to print m3 ============")
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println("============  about to print m4 ============")
}
```

Comment: `curl -G https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/1/public/values?alt=json` gives some output starting with `{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xml` so `feed` certainly doesn't contain a version field ...

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, your definition of `GSSS` is wrong.

This works a bit better:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type GSSS struct {
    Version string `json:"version"`
    Feed GSSSfeed `json:"feed"`
}

type GSSSfeed struct {
    TITLE   GSSTitle `json:"title"`
    // Entry   []GSSSEntry `json:"entry"`
}
type GSSTitle struct {
    T string `json:"$t"`
}

func main() {
    url01 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/1/public/values?alt=json"
    //url02 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/2/public/values?alt=json"
    //url03 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/3/public/values?alt=json"
    //url04 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/4/public/values?alt=json"
    //url05 := "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/168xdxefP3gGnrTGg2hwJoeRVfmbEuTB5plFTyd6I5Qo/5/public/values?alt=json"
    println("=============  starting main =============")

    // res, err := http.Get("https://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
    res, err := http.Get(url01)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err.Error())
    // }

    var m GSSS
    // err := json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
    //json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&m)
    // json.NewDecoder([]byte(body)).Decode(&m)

    // json.NewDecoder([]byte(res.Body)).Decode(&m)
    json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&m)

    //err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Whoops...:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("============  about to print m3 ============")
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println("============  about to print m4 ============")
}
```